# MySQL: dates before 1970

Tags: php, mysql, types, date

I'm working on a church site which has many events before `1970`, these events starts from `1001` to today, how can I store the dates in `MySQL`?

```
$y = $_REQUEST["year"];
$m = $_REQUEST["month"];
$d = $_REQUEST["day"];

$date = date("Y-m-d", "$y/$m/$d");
```

This works fine only for dates after `1970`, how can I store dates before this year?

What kind of datatype should I have in `MySQL`? Now I've set my column to `date` type

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`DATE` is fine. It can store values [from 1000 to 9999 AD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

> The DATE type is used when you need only a date value, without a time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

It's different with PHP's old-style date functions (`date()`, `strtotime()`....) these work with UNIX timestamps and, when using 32-bit values, are limited to a date range from 1970 to 2038.

To work with date values beyond that, work with PHP 5's [new object-oriented `DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: No dates before the year 1000? Let's say you want to store your birthday. What would Jesus do?

Comment: @Wouter heh! :) @ajreal had the solution for that in his (now deleted) answer, store the year as a separate signed int. I don't think `DATE` can do that