# How to get the real date and not the actual

Tags: mysql, date, parsing

I'm trying to implement this query:

```
SELECT 
    str_to_date(concat(Right(Born,2),"/", Mid(Born,6,2),"/",Left(Born,4)),'%d/%m/%y') as Born_Date,

    str_to_date(concat(Right(FirstTime,2),"/", Mid(FirstTime,6,2),"/",Left(FirstTime,4)),'%d/%m/%y') as First_Date

    FROM ItalianAthletes
    where Born is not null and char_length(born)=10
          and FirstTime is not null
```

I have this format as date in my database (example): 22-07-1877.

But in place of this date I get: 2018-07-22

How to get 1877 instead of 2018?

Comment: 1877 is before 1970 ...  
 There's an answer on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466546/mysql-working-with-dates-before-1970

Comment: @Zak The answer there says that MySQL already does it correctly, the problem was with PHP. But this question has no PHP.

Comment: "real date and not the actual" -- what's the difference between real and actual?

Comment: @Barmar You're right I didn't explain well, for real date I intend the date I have inside my database field, actual date I intended the present date (even if it gets a future date)

Answer (score 3):

You're using `%y` which is for two-digit years, you should use `%Y`.

Also there should be no reason to do all that work with LEFT(), RIGHT(), and MID(). You can use dashes instead of slashes in the format string of STR_TO_DATE().

```
mysql> set @born = '22-07-1877';

mysql> select str_to_date(@born, '%d-%m-%Y');
+--------------------------------+
| str_to_date(@born, '%d-%m-%Y') |
+--------------------------------+
| 1877-07-22                     |
+--------------------------------+
```

Please consider using a real DATE column instead of using VARCHAR for your dates. It'll be simpler to do date arithmetic, date functions, sorting, searching, etc.

Prefer to format it into dd-mm-YYYY in your presentation layer.

Comment: Yeah, I thought to use a real date column, but in that field I could have not ever a complete date, sometimes I have also year and month only, other times I could have year only. So I thought it could be better make a string to date converter inside the queries.